# Report Folder Sharing setting SFDC bug?

Tags: reporting, permissions, folder

### Background

We need to configure a folder "`Company X Reports`" which has to:

1. Everybody can view
2. One profile called **Supervisor** can clone reports from there and save only in "My Personal Custom Reports"
3. Finally, other profile called **Manager** that have to edit the reports on `Company X Reports`

### Current Approach

1. I've created the folder and set the Share permission to: Group `All internal Users` > **Viewer**
2. I've created the Supervisor profile and set enabled: `Create and Customize Reports, Edit My Reports, Report Builder, Run Reports`. All other permission related to reports or folder are disabled.
3. I've created the Manager profile with the same previous permissions plus "`Manage Reports in Public Folders`".

[image]

### Result

Other users have readonly permission on the folder reports which is ok. The manager is working fine, But the Supervisor can view, can clone reports on that folder, and that is ok. **But it can create new reports and save in that folder.**

### Question

I cant figure out **why the Supervisor user is able to save new reports in the "Company X Reports" folder. When he only has viewer permission.**
Is this a SFDC bug?

Comment: You would think that the Supervisor profile only having the [Create and Customize Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=analytics_sharing_permissions.htm&language=en_US) permission would have granted create permissions to My Personal Custom Reports and shared folders if the sharing rights allow it. What happens if you temporarily remove that permission?

Comment: First thank you for your interest on this question. If I remove Create and Customize Reports then the new report or the button save as are not shown any more. 
It is any way to grant writing (create/edit reports) permissions only for one folder ?

Comment: I think that I'm going to open a case. 110 Views and not comments is quite estrange for this forum.

Comment: It's a tough one. It seems like how you've set it up should work as you expect. Since it isn't there is probably either a bug or some other subtlety (undocumented?) in play here.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that is actually by design, "Change/move/delete your own reports or dashboards in the folder" for "Viewers", according to the help and training article "[Comparing Access Levels for Report and Dashboard Folders](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=analytics_folder_access_chart.htm&language=en_US)".
[image]

Comment: Seems odd that Viewer can write in the folder- But SFDC always surprise me .

Comment: If you turn off the "Enable access levels for sharing report and dashboard folders" in Setup -> Reports and Dashboards -> Folder sharing, then I believe it will behave the way you want.

Comment: I've tried but doesn't work by disabling Folder Sharing. Instead of fix, now the user with that profile now can't see the custom new folder but they now can see all other folders.

Comment: It looks like you'd have to redo the sharing on the folders after you disable it and possibly create any folders that were created after it was enabled. According to note on https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=analytics_sharing_enable.htm